# HTSQL generated MySQL query is extremely slow

Tags: mysql, sql, htsql

I have a database with two tables:

adjectives - ID primary key; NAME varchar;
adjectives_reviews - ID primary key; ADJECTIVE_ID foreign key; REVIEW_ID foreign key; COUNT int

I want to get a list of distinct ADJECTIVE_ID from adjectives_reviews with a sum of the values in the 'COUNT' column across all rows with the same ADJECTIVE_ID.

The adjectives table has 46,000 rows and adjectives_reviews has ~2,849,708 .

I am using the following HTSQL query:

> /adjectives{name,sum(adjectives_reviews.count)}

which gets translated to SQL:

```
SELECT `adjectives`.`name`,
       COALESCE(`adjectives_reviews`.`sum`, 0)
FROM `adjectives`
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CAST(SUM(`adjectives_reviews`.`count`) AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS `sum`,
                             `adjectives_reviews`.`adjective_id`
                      FROM `adjectives_reviews`
                      GROUP BY 2) AS `adjectives_reviews`
                     ON (`adjectives`.`id` = `adjectives_reviews`.`adjective_id`)
ORDER BY `adjectives`.`id` ASC
```

This query produces the result I want but it is too slow. It is so slow in fact that the HTTP server times out and I cannot get the output CSV file which I need. I am looking for a way to optimize this query or alternatively a way to get the output as CSV without using the HTTP interface of HTSQL.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the result out as CSV by using the native mysql client and adding 3 lines to the query:

```
SELECT `adjectives`.`name`,
       COALESCE(`adjectives_reviews`.`sum`, 0)
FROM `adjectives`
     LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT CAST(SUM(`adjectives_reviews`.`count`) AS SIGNED INTEGER) AS `sum`,
                             `adjectives_reviews`.`adjective_id`
                      FROM `adjectives_reviews`
                      GROUP BY 2) AS `adjectives_reviews`
                     ON (`adjectives`.`id` = `adjectives_reviews`.`adjective_id`)
ORDER BY `adjectives`.`id` ASC
INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/adjectives.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

It ran reasonably fast.